# How to set space between x axis labels in IOS Line Charts?

Tags: swift, charts

I have been facing this problem for a long time. I wish to set equal space between the x-axis labels in my iOS chart. I referred to this solution and applied the code as

```
lineChartView.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = true
```

but it didn't work out. Then I did set the value to be false then it gave me somewhat equal spacing but now my first and last x-axis label is being hidden in the chart. Please help me out with this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple add this code:

```
barChartView.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(6)
barChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1.0
barChartView.leftAxis.granularity = 1.0
```